# USB serial adapter not showing as /dev/ttyUSBn

Tags: usb, usb-modem

I have an old system running 14.04 LTS with a USB/RS232 adapter to connect a modem. It was working well until I had to restore the system disk from a backup - only 4 days old, fortunately :-)

Now I connect the USB cable and it shows up on lsusb but /dev/ttyUSB0 is not being created.

lsusb output:

```
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
```

syslog when connecting:

```
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.332695] usb 5-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.432551] usb 5-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.432553] usb 5-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.432554] usb 5-1.4: Product: USB FAST SERIAL ADAPTER
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.432555] usb 5-1.4: Manufacturer: FTDI
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk kernel: [189143.432555] usb 5-1.4: SerialNumber: FTB9JFF6
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk mtp-probe: checking bus 5, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/usb5/5-1/5-1.4"
Apr 19 17:39:18 tomahawk mtp-probe: bus: 5, device: 5 was not an MTP device
```

Any ideas on what might be missing?

TIA

Fernando

Comment: You probably need to reinstall the FTDI driver for it. In `terminal` type `dkms status` and lets see what we get.

Comment: "dkms status" comes up empty... :-/

Comment: I've come to realize that I probably did a mistake in reinstalling the desktop image instead of the server image. My lsmod output is very small:

Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
psmouse               122880  0
ahci                   36864  3
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
fjes                   28672  0

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The process I used to restore the system was:

1. install a fresh 14.04 on a new boot disk
2. restore everything from backup except /boot

Since I had the system up-to-date, I hoped there would be no problems with this. Almost...

Strangely, the fresh install left me with a 4.40 linux kernel, which is not part of the distribution. So, when I restored /lib, the 4.40 kernel modules where replaced by the 3.13 ones. This meant that the FTDI module was not being loaded anymore.

The solution was to force the reinstall of the 3.13 kernel and manually remove the 4.40 kernel files from /boot. After running update-grub, everything was back to normal.

Thanks for the pointing the right direction @heynnema